# What's wrong with this statement on x86-64?

Tags: c, linux, assembly, x86-64

This function aims to get the start address of the stack:

```
unsigned long find_start(void){
        __asm__("movq %rsp, %eax");
}
```

When I compile it,getting an error:

```
Error: suffix or operands invalid for `movq'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`movq` is an instruction that expects 64-bit operands. `rsp` is a 64-bit register, while `eax` is a 32-bit register.

Perhaps try `rax`?

Comment: It works now.But isn't the start address of the stack fixed in linux?The output is different each time...

Comment: Modern Linux systems tend to randomize address space a bit, as an effort to thwart the most simple of buffer overflow attacks (this does not prevent the overflow, but makes life harder for the attacker nonetheless). So the stack will begin at a different address each time. Use `sysctl -w kernel.randomize_va_space=0` (as root) to deactivate that behavior (until next boot).

Answer (score 1):

`%eax` is the 32-bit GP register.  However you are trying to do a 64-bit move with it.  It should be `%rax`.

Comment: It works now.But isn't the start address of the stack fixed in linux?The output is different each time...

Comment: @mysql: The stack pointer points to the top of the stack.  So as your program progresses, this value will fluctuate as the stack gets used.  I don't know of a nice way to find the start of the stack, that's best left for a different question.

Answer (score 1):

You need, as stated, to use the 64-bit register %rax.

Regarding the fact that the stack pointer is different each time, I suspect that you are seeing the results of *[address space layout randomization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization)*, and in real time at that...