# Isn't the start address of the stack fixed in linux?

Tags: linux, stack

```
unsigned long find_start(void){
    __asm__("movq %rsp, %rax");
}
int main(){
    printf ("OX%x\n" , find_start()) ;
}
```

This is a further question of [my previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5691345/whats-wrong-with-this-statement-on-x86-64),

the output is different each time I run the programe.

isn't the start address of the stack fixed in linux?

The kernel version is **2.6.18-194.el5**

*Update from comments:* I'm now trying to do a hello world exploit,how to overcome this?Will the process created by execve be using the same stack start address as its parent process?

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps you're seeing the effect of [address space layout randomization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization).  It's a security feature, to make it harder to exploit stack or buffer overruns.

Comment: Will the process created by `execve` be using the same stack  start address as its parent process?

Comment: @mysql_go, no, as `execve` asks kernel to reload of elf image. Memory layout is depends on elf image, so it is recomputed for `exec`ed process.

Comment: @osgx,how to locate the shell code if that is exactly the case?

Comment: Write a test program which will print address of some variable stored on stack (e.g. `int f(){int a;printf("%p\n",&a);}int main(){f();}`).

Comment: @mysql_go: As I understand it, execve should re-randomize the layout; however, if the call happens within the same entropy update window as when the parent process was started, the child process can end up with the same layout as the parent. Check out this link: http://www.sophsec.com/research/aslr_research.html

Comment: @osgx,no shell code exploitation depends on the fact that the initial start address of the stack is fixed.

Comment: @Jim Lewis, good link, but I can't agree that layout will be the same, as there is a `" + jiffies"` part in formula. Layout is same only for child, execed in the same jiffle (in classic kernel it is 10 or 1 millisecond time) when parent was started.

Answer (score 0):

See [Pseudo-random stack pointer under Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921485/pseudo-random-stack-pointer-under-linux)

Answer (score -1):

How would that be possible on an operating system that supports multiple processes and multiple threads?

EDIT: I should mention what I brought up in the comments: [Address Space Layout Randomization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization), a security feature that deliberately scrambles the address around.

Comment: The address is virtual,and will finally be mapped into real address by OS.

Comment: A process shares the same virtual address space across its threads.

Comment: One can't inference whether the initial stack address is fixed or not by "a process shares the same virtual address space across its threads",right?

Comment: Irrelevant. My point is that there is no reason to have the same virtual address for the stack. Why have something that creates a specific virtual address for one arbitrary stack? In fact, Linux deliberately uses a different address as a security measure: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization

Comment: Probably ASLR is the key.I'm now trying to do a hello world exploit,how to overcome this?Will the process created by `execve` be using the same stack start address as its parent process?

Comment: If we consider a Linux kernel without support of ASLR (turned off or before it was added to kernel), virtual addresses will be similar.

Comment: @osgx,similar or exactly the same? I mean the stack start address.

Comment: Just try. To turn off ASLR you can do "`echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space`" as root.

Comment: @osgx,I just tried,and the address is fixed if I turn off ASLR.